# php бот telegramm

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Есть у кого кусочек рабочего кода с отправкой в телеграмм-чат (чат бот стандартный, api телеграмма) сообщения и кнопки под ним, типа "принять", чтобы эту кнопку можно было отловить: понять к какому сообщению и какой пользователь её нажал. 
В интернете находил только про создание меню, но мне надо именно inline с вривязкой к сообщению

Answer (score 1):

Это код отправки сообщения (на Python) с двумя кнопками внизу:

```
data = '{"inline_keyboard": [[{"text":"pong", "callback_data":"pong"},{"text":"ping", "callback_data":"ping"}]]}'
url = "https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=ID&text=test buttons&reply_markup=" + data 
r = requests.post(url)
```

Если кто то нажмет на какую нибудь кнопку, бот получит ответ:

```
{"update_id":111,"callback_query":{"id":"111","from":{"id":111,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Имя","last_name":"Фамилия","language_code":"ru"},"message":{"message_id":8930,"from":{"id":111,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"Bot","username":"Bot"},"chat":{"id":111,"first_name":"Имя","last_name":"Фамилия","type":"private"},"date":1566360285,"text":"test buttons","reply_markup":{"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"pong","callback_data":"pong"},{"text":"ping","callback_data":"ping"}]]}},"chat_instance":"111","data":"pong"}}
```

Ключ "callback_query", говорит что это нажатие на кнопку отправленного ботом сообщения, "from" - кто нажал, "message" - в каком из сообщений бота нажали кнопку (вдруг вы их несколько отправили, в таком случае при отправке выдергивайте id каждого сообщения, из ответа телеграма и где нить записывайте, id отправленного сообщения и id ответа - одинаковые), ну а понять на какую кнопку нажали можно по самому последнему ключу "data":"pong"...

Comment: а ответ приходит на зарегистрированную для бота страницу и в массиве POST?

Comment: Да, ответ приходит на веб-хук. Если веб-хука нет, то, я думаю, вы увидите ответ через getupdates...

Comment: Благодарю! Вы мне очень помогли!